# lambda to delete all elements in collection which comply with Predict

Tags: c#, collections, lambda

i wan't to remove all sales according to predict expression

```
  IQueryable<Sale> sales = entites.Sales.Where<Sale>(s => s.EmployeeId == check.EmployeeId);
  foreach (Sale sale in sales)
            entites.Sales.DeleteObject(sale);
```

i'm looking for a lambda which can do this in one line of code .
selecting and deleting .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sarcastic Version:

```
IQueryable<Sale> sales = entites.Sales.Where<Sale>(s => s.EmployeeId == check.EmployeeId); foreach (Sale sale in sales) entites.Sales.DeleteObject(sale);
```

Another Version:

```
var sales = entites.Sales.Where<Sale>(s => s.EmployeeId == check.EmployeeId).ToList().ForEach(entites.Sales.DeleteObject);
```

Comment: yeah , it looks kinda ridicules at this point but still it's still good practice ...
but who gets the V ?
Ritch or John ..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built in extension method for ForEach in System.Linq.Enumerable.  You can easily create your own though:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T element in sequence)
    {
        action(element);
        yield return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is on the List<T> class. Yay .Net 2.0.

Comment: Well would you look at that!  I had no idea.  Thanks.  I've always wondered why ForEach wasn't included in System.Linq.Enumerable.

Comment: That's a fairly large debate. Some gibberish about side-effects. I disagree. So do my coworkers and the reactive extensions people. Our version is here: http://elevate.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/09e446b554f8#src%2fElevate%2fEnumerableExtensions.cs